# Swift guard let error: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[String : String]' in swift?

Tags: swift, conditional-statements

I am getting the following error at the line of code below. My app crashes when the value is nil/empty, hence why I am trying to guard unwrap.

**Error:**  **Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[String : String]'**

```
guard let savedByUsers = venue.childSnapshot(forPath: "bookmarkedByUsers").value as! [String : String] else { return }
```

Comment: `as!` -> `as?`  Conditionally unwrapping something you already force unwrapped is redundant.

Comment: did you tried @JohnMontgomery suggestion ?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery the suggestion is also included in the suggestion below.

Answer (score 2):

change to:

```
guard let savedByUsers: [String: String] = venue.childSnapshot(forPath: "bookmarkedByUsers").value as? [String: String] else {
    return
}
```

The `as!` forces the unwrap and causes an exception when the value is `nil`. Using `as?` will avoid that and jump into the `else` clause.

Comment: I updated my code to your suggestion, but now I'm getting a "Cannot subscript a value of incorrect or ambiguous type" error.

Comment: I left out the `:` after `savedByUsers`. I edited, try now

Comment: my app is halting executing at that line and does not proceed. There are no  values currently in my data structure so its returning null, but I thought the else { return } should break out and continue execution but is not, why is that?

Comment: @Roggie No, the return statement ends the execution. What the guard let statement basically says is "Make sure that this is true, or that this value exists. If not, execute the code within the curly brackets." Which in this case is a return statement.